# Java SWT: Getting original X/Y Coordinates from Scaled Image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, swt

I have an image where

```
Height = 1300
Width = 1300
```

I scaled the image to:
    ScaledHeight = 700
    ScaledWidth = 700

I am using the following to get the original Coordinates:

```
public Coordinate GetScaledXYCoordinate(int oldX, int oldY, int width, int height, int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight)
{       
    int newX = (int)(oldX * width)/scaledWidth;
    int newY = (int)(oldY * height)/scaledHeight;

    Coordinate retXY = new Coordinate(newX, newY);
    return retXY;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have updated to include answer

Comment: Can you please add example input and the corresponding output of your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
int width = 1300;
int scaledWidth = 700;
```

the value of `(width/scaledWidth)` is **1** - you are doing integer arithmetic not floating point.

Use

```
int newX = (oldX * width) /scaledWidth;
int newY = (oldY * height) /scaledHeight;
```

to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help @greg-449